# Facebook Send Button: 'Sorry, something went wrong'

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm implementing a Facebook Send dialog, by opening `facebook.com/dialog/send` in a popup window. When I click the 'Send' button the dialog will display the error: 'Sorry, something went wrong' – but only for certain link URLs. The best examples I have are:

Not Working:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send
    ?app_id=12345
    &name=Example
    &link=facebook.com/examplepage
    &redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response
```

Working:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send
    ?app_id=12345
    &name=Example
    &link=google.com
    &redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response
```

These links are identical except that the first one shares 'facebook.com' and the second one shares 'google.com'. Only the second one works.

The same errors occur if I use the Facebook JavaScript API with `FB.ui({method: 'send'})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Both the links now work for me, although I have not changed anything. I can only hypothesise that Facebook has either fixed this bug, or this issue occurs on some internet connections and not others.

Answer (score 0):

I think Facebook is trying to read the URL and pre-populate the image and content. In your case probably because skiggle.com.au is a redirected to the other domain and facebook doesn't accept it.

Edit. Your first link works though

Comment: The first link loads, but when you actually type in a name and click the 'Send' button, it errors for me. Thanks for your input though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem & worked out that this was due to linking to a Facebook page that did not have a vanity URL set up (i.e. http://www.facebook.com/CubicMushroom rather than http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=261963707177053).  If you set up a vanity URL for the page it seems to work OK (providing you link to the vanity URL version of the page URL).

To claim a vanity URL, once you have a certain no of like (it used to be 25, but think it's a little lower now) visit https://www.facebook.com/username/

Comment: Didn't work for me but thanks for your suggestion. The Facebook link in the question includes a link to a vanity URL (facebook.com/iselect). Adding http:// also doesn't help, unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you share a link to `localhost`