# Feed dialog to event/fan page says "Sorry, something went wrong." after clicking share

Tags: facebook, dialog, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps

Having some issues with the feed dialog when attempting to post to a event or fan page. In my application I am using the JS API and FB.ui using the method feed.

But for a demonstration you can do it using the feed url too for example:

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=131727613511269&to=287203454659917&redirect_uri=http://www.timeanddate.com/

After clicking share you get the:

> **Sorry, something went wrong.**
>
> We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.

Where:

**app_id**       = your app

**to**           = a event / fan page

**redirect_uri** = a url you are allowed to redirect to

note that the app has **publish_stream** permissions. (it also has manage_pages for fan pages)

The app in question by the way is: http://apps.facebook.com/tndcountdown/

Thanks,

Andy

EDIT:

An Example taken straight from the documentation:

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=123050457758183&link=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&name=Facebook%20Dialogs&caption=Reference%20Documentation&description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response&to=287203454659917

just replace to=287203454659917 with an event.. (make a test one like it did there)

Answer (score 0):

A few issues I've run into will dialog is that Facebook tries to fill in any missing data. So if you don't provide a description and caption, Facebook will try to scrape the page to get that content. Depending on how the page responds to the "scraping" Facebook will error out. I always make sure I include at least a space for those fields.

It seems the feed url you provided is similar to what is in the documentation. But the demo in the documentation has extra parameters.
I'm about to add page support to my Facebook app, which does the same thing as yours. 
http://apps.facebook.com/countdown-timer/

Comment: in the app itself it uses pretty much every parameter :D but for example thou http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=131727613511269&to=287203454659917&redirect_uri=http://www.timeanddate.com/&description=test&caption=testy leads to the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

As I posted here - [Facebook Send Button - 'Sorry, something went wrong.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408052/facebook-send-button-sorry-something-went-wrong/8877974#8877974)...

I had the same problem & worked out that this was due to linking to a Facebook page that did not have a vanity URL set up (i.e. http://www.facebook.com/CubicMushroom rather than http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=261963707177053).  If you set up a vanity URL for the page it seems to work OK (providing you link to the vanity URL version of the page URL).

To claim a vanity URL, once you have a certain no of like (it used to be 25, but think it's a little lower now) visit https://www.facebook.com/username/